# how to apply field on cell Template using ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

i am using ng-grid so in my case for every row i have edit n delete option for a single row data so user can edit and update sp my question how can i pass field in cell template currently my code is that but i am not getting _id as field in function that i used in template for ng-click. _id is basically field for every unique 
Here is output you can see in image.

second thing how to shrink last column of cell template .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yneQL.png

**StoresController.js**

```
  $scope.stores = [

            {
                "_id" : "1s445ggfg",
                "name" : "kj",
                "address1" : "sdf",
                "address2" : "sdf",
                "latitude" : "12",
                "longitude" : "12"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "2s45ggfg",
                "name" : "kddsj",
                "address1" : "sdsfdf",
                "address2" : "ssdfdf",
                "latitude" : "23",
                "longitude" : "23"
            }

        ];


        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'stores',
            jqueryUITheme: true,
            columnDefs:
                [
                    {field:'name', displayName:'Name'},
                    {field:'address1', displayName:'Address 1'},
                    {field:'address2', displayName:'Address 2'},
                    {field:'latitude', displayName:'Latitude'},
                    {field:'longitude', displayName:'Longitude'},
                    {field:'', displayName:'', cellTemplate: '<a ng-click="openStoreModal(_id)" id="edit"  data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw colorInfo" ></i></a><a ng-click="deleteStore(_id)"  id="delete"  data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>'}

                ]
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `ng-click="deleteStore(_id)"` to `ng-click="deleteStore(row.getProperty('_id'))` or `ng-click="deleteStore(row.entity._id)"`

And for the size of the last column (100px in this example)…

```
{field:'', displayName:'', cellTemplate: editDeleteCellTemplate, maxWidth: 100 }
```

Comment: can you tell me what's problem jqueryUItheme:true is not working for me is there any css or js file needed ? except ng-grid.js and its css file @Kabb5

Comment: @Wajihurrehman - I have not used the jQuery UI Theme on my ng-grids, sorry

Comment: Where is the documentation for the row and col objects? The angular docs show them in examples but nowhere can I find the actual object references that describe the objects?

Answer (score 1):

@bob ,

There is a Question that covers some aspects that is : [ng-grid headerRowTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118882/ng-grid-headerrowtemplate-has-anyone-used-this)

and You can have Reference for Templating [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating) that might be helpful as well.